# Android Layout Design with background blacked out

Tags: android, xml, layout, popup

I need to create a layout where there is a list view in the background. When the button cross at the bottom is clicked the whole background is blurred and one left corner of the area will be shown little white with some icons (search and Add).

This is similar to the functionality as in Path Android app, plus button is clicked.

I am new to such layout can someone tell me how can i implement this on Android.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's very unlikely that someone will just write the code for you. What have you done so far?

Comment: sounds like sliding menu :) please check it in google market

Answer (score 0):

You can try one thing. Create another activity with the icon at the corner. When ever you press the specific button start this activity. And in the manifest of the activity use

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
```

Now when you are clicking the button another activity with transparent background will start over it. Usually the back activity will be little bit blur. But if you want your custom design you can use your custom background in the second activity.

Comment: I cant call an activity from this activity because when i click this icon at the corner i get few more icons, these icons will be like search, add delete etc. When i click search this area blur area with icons should disappear and a search bar should drop from top section. So is there any other way to do it ?